# How to make piston devices in Minecraft Education?

Tags: minecraft-redstone, minecraft-education-edition

Every time I make a moving piston device in Education Edition, I have to reactivate it again constantly. Is there a way to prevent this or reduce the lag it causes?

I am using a 2015 MacBook air with Minecraft Education 1.18.32